# react-scripts build ignores css files when bundling

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, react-scripts

I'm trying to build a project using create-react-app.

My project use a package that contains it's own css.

I've created my own custom css file to overwrite the package css and imported it in the index.js file. `import './custom.css';`

Locally and before running `npm run build` it works as expected. custom.css override the package css file when needed. But after running the command and with the css bundled into one file it doesn't work anymore ( since locally it's overriding the css because `import './custom.css';` is ran after the package css file )

Does anyone know how to make it work ?

The only way i can think off include directly importing the css file in the generated index.html after the bundled css file but that seem very very error prone.